# Had 130 rep removed and all I get is "User was removed"

Tags: discussion, feature-request

So, all you get told is "User was removed", why not at least tell us which question(s) were affected so we know.

Bad enough we did not deserve to loose the rep... but at least telling us which questions could make us feel better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way that the system works.

For a more in-depth discussion, see this post on meta.stackexchange.com [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/282289)

Comment: It's about being told which questions were affected which would be nice...

Comment: @SolarMike - it's a network wide policy.  Your (favorite) local site mods have zero ability to modify it.  For that matter, we don't even have tools to identify which user was removed.

Comment: @GlenH7 having seen 220 disappear is just gutting when some who post questions get answers and can’t even be bothered to vote...

Comment: @SolarMike FWIW, you're not alone on this round.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328644/194162

Comment: @GlenH7 Thanks for thinking of me ! I'll live and continue.

Comment: @SolarMike if its any consolation i lost about three times that much network wide. Best not  to think about it too much. Its not a big deal.

Comment: @joojaa was hoping for at least which q or a but won't happen, never mind... We survive it.